# Worklight support for OAuth and SAML

Tags: oauth-2.0, ibm-mobilefirst, saml-2.0, worklight-security

Given that if we are running on a full WebSphere Application Server v8.5.5 profile which has support for both OAuth and SAML ( http://ibm.co/1bUqrJJ  and  http://ibm.co/1es8Hgv ), Can a Worklight 6.1 environment take advantage of either without needing some other external authorization service such as a DataPower or ISAM in between the device and the Worklight Server?

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Worklight (5.0.x, 6.0.0.x, 6.1.0) does not provide any OAuth support on either the client or server. So any integration you're going to do will require some work on your part.

See related questions about Worklight and OAuth:

- [How to implement OAUTH 2.0 in IBM Worklight 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438856/how-to-implement-oauth-2-0-in-ibm-worklight-6-0)
- [IBM Worklight - How to use Google authentication in a Hybrid application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943745/ibm-worklight-how-to-use-google-authentication-in-a-hybrid-application)

OAuth support is something that Worklight product designers are thinking about, but I cannot comment further.