# how to login with google account

Tags: authentication, gmail, ibm-mobilefirst, gmail-api, google-signin

We want to log in with any Google account.
We created the client_id, client_secret from google developers.

Anyone please tell me how to do.
Whatever we do that code posted below

**OAuth 2.0 client IDs type is webapplication**

I got this  Error: **invalid_client The OAuth client was not found**

[image]

please any one why it is coming

```js
var CLIENT_ID = '349212001841-t1qnhfhp7ail46dh5rn1t6vdc10op93l.apps.googleusercontent.com';
   
    var SCOPES = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly' ];
   
    function checkAuth() {
     gapi.auth.authorize({
      'client_id' : CLIENT_ID,
      'scope' : SCOPES.join(' '),
      'immediate' : true
     }, handleAuthResult);
    }
   
    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
     var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
     if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
      loadGmailApi();
     } else {
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
     }
    }
   
    function handleAuthClick(event) {
     gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id : CLIENT_ID,
      scope : SCOPES,
      immediate : false
     }, handleAuthResult);
     return false;
    }
   
    function loadGmailApi() {
     gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', listLabels);
    }
   
    function listLabels() {
     var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
      'userId' : 'me'
     });
   
     request.execute(function(resp) {
      var labels = resp.labels;
      appendPre('Labels:');
   
      if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
       for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var label = labels[i];
        appendPre(label.name)
       }
      } else {
       appendPre('No Labels found.');
      }
     });
    }
   
   function appendPre(message) {
     var pre = document.getElementById('output');
     var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
     pre.appendChild(textContent);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>LoginSN</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
      <!--
       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
       <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
      -->
      <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
      <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
      <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth"/></script>
      
  </head>
  
     <body style="display: none;">
     
      <div data-role="page" id="loginPage">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        <h1 id="fb-welcome"></h1>
     <label for="text">User Name:</label><input type="text" name="text" id="unL">
     <label for="text">Password:</label><input type="password" name="text" id="pwdL">
     <a href="#dashboardPage" data-role="button" id="buttonLn">LOGIN</a>
     <a href="#registrationPage" data-role="button" id="buttonRe">REGISRASTION</a>
     <a href="#" data-role="button" id="buttonF" onclick="fblogin()">via Facebook Login</a>
     <!-- <a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">via Google Login</a> -->
     <!-- <a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" onclick="callGoogle()">via Google Login</a>  -->
     
     <!--  <a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" onclick="login('google')">via Google Login</a>  -->
     <div id="authorize-div" >
       <span>Authorize access to Gmail API</span>
       <a href="#" data-role="button" id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">via Google Login</a>
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
          <div data-role="page" id="dashboardPage">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick='Logout();'>LogOut</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
      
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am not able to see google login pop in my application

Comment: Looks here for similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943745/ibm-worklight-how-to-use-google-authentication-in-a-hybrid-application

Comment: Idan i modified the question and code please find it. i got error why it is coming please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have missed adding the javascript of Google, `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">`

Based on the Code sample of Google in their [document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
  // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
  var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';

  var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];

  /**
   * Check if current user has authorized this application.
   */
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
      }, handleAuthResult);
  }

  /**
   * Handle response from authorization server.
   *
   * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
   */
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
      loadGmailApi();
    } else {
      // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
      // clicking authorize button.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    }
  }

  /**
   * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
   *
   * @param {Event} event Button click event.
   */
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
      handleAuthResult);
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Load Gmail API client library. List labels once client library
   * is loaded.
   */
  function loadGmailApi() {
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', listLabels);
  }

  /**
   * Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox. If no labels
   * are found an appropriate message is printed.
   */
  function listLabels() {
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
      'userId': 'me'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var labels = resp.labels;
      appendPre('Labels:');

      if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
          var label = labels[i];
          appendPre(label.name)
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No Labels found.');
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
   * as its text node.
   *
   * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
   */
  function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('output');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }

</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="authorize-div" style="display: none">
  <span>Authorize access to Gmail API</span>
  <!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
  <button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
    Authorize
  </button>
 </div>
 <pre id="output"></pre>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Kindly add that, and I think that should work. Update us if there is any progress.

Comment: thanks so much Rebot for give reply. i have an doubt in Developer Console for creating client id i.e which one type should be take it like android or webapp. Because we developing this app for the hybrid mobile application in worklight 7.1.

Comment: Rebot i got  it this error Error: invalid_client. The OAuth client was not found. when click on button it opening one window and showing like above error.i attached screen shot in question please find

Comment: invalid_client. The OAuth client was not found error is comming. No error in the error log, just the page load error quoted here. i try to solve all ways using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166848/invalid-client-in-google-oauth2

Comment: i got an error i.e invalid request,invalid parameter value for origin:missing authority:file://

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have <> around the client id. You do not want those.

Comment: Tony,sorry i am not get it to you.

Comment: @kranti, in your first picture, I see client_id=<34921..., it should not have <. it should be client_id=34921...